# Getting values for a Model property from a Web API call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, profiling

Currently I'm populating dropdowns options using an API call. In my model I have something like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> getOptions
        {
            get
            {
                var options = WebApiHelper.Download<IEnumerable<T>>(
                "Controller");
                var dropDownOptions = options.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.Value }).ToList();
                return dropDownOptions;
            }
        }
```

And this is called in a couple of places in the .cshtml (e.g. see below):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.someProperty, Model.getOptions)

List<SelectListItem> GetDropdownOptions()
        {
            var currentDropdownItems = Model.getOptions;
            //some other code to modify dropdown options.
        }
```

Will the Web API only be hit once when I call Model.getOptions? Or will it be called every time since it is inside the get for that property? If it is the latter, what is a good work around for that issue?

Edit: thought about it a little more, would it be better to have these controller populate the values for that property? I have a feeling that an api call gets placed on every call to model.getoptions.

Comment: Yes, your database will be called each time you access the property. Make your property `public List<SelectListItem> getOptions { get; set; }` and and set the value in the controller - a view model property should not be calling a database (and your current implementation means its impossible to unit test)

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling as such. If you'd like to submit that as an answer I can give it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `WebApiHelper.Download()` will be called each time you access the property and, if you were editing a collection, your current implementation could seriously degrade performance.

While you could define a private field (say) `private List<SelectListItem> _Options;` and in the getter, check if its `null` and if so, populate it using your `WebApiHelper.Download()` method, and then `return _Options;` this is still not a preferred implementation since you cannot easily unit test your app.

```
private List<SelectListItem> _options;
public List<SelectListItem> getOptions
{
  get
  {
    if (_options == null)
    {
      _options = // call your service
    }
    return _options;
  }
}
```

Keep your view models as dumb as possible and make your property

```
public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
```

and in the controller, initialize your model and call `WebApiHelper.Download()` to populate the collection (and inject `WebApiHelper` into your controller)